# Accuracy assessment in R?

Tags: r, accuracy

I would like to prepare a confusion matrix from  decision tree module in R.

Can anyone help me with the code that is needed for calculating user, producer and overall accuracy along with kappa values in R?

My confusion matrix looks like this

```
                       Leaf-off Trees Leaf_on Trees
  Leaf-off Trees             41            10
  Leaf-on Trees               1            46
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not much of a GIS question and you should make it into a reproducible example and try StackOverflow.

Comment: User and producer accuracy are related to remote sensing, so I think it isn't off-topic. This post needs a reproducible example to become a good question.

Answer (score 5):

Post a reproducible example for a better solution of your problem. I will use a personal example to show you:

```
          Reference
Prediction      FPers      FCadu      Prade      SinVg
     FPers  9.8039216  0.0000000  1.3071895  0.0000000
     FCadu  0.0000000 49.0196078  3.9215686  0.0000000
     Prade  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.6535948  0.0000000
     SinVg  0.0000000  0.0000000  1.9607843 33.3333333
```

For producer and user accuracy:

```
# User accuracy
diag(matrix) /rowSums(matrix)
    FPers     FCadu     Prade     SinVg 
0.8823529 0.9259259 1.0000000 0.9444444 

# Producer accuracy
diag(matrix)/colSums(matrix)
     FPers      FCadu      Prade      SinVg 
1.00000000 1.00000000 0.08333333 1.00000000
```

For overall accuracy, make a small loop:

```
sums <- vector()

for(i in 1:dim(matrix)[1]){
  sums[i] <- matrix[i,i]
}

o.accuracy <- sum(sums)/sum(matrix)
92.81046
```

Finally, to calculate Kappa, use `psych` package.

```
library(psych)

cohen.kappa(matrix) # you can set your number of observations

Call: cohen.kappa1(x = x, w = w, n.obs = n.obs, alpha = alpha)

Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate upper
unweighted kappa  0.80     0.88  0.96
weighted kappa    0.91     0.95  1.00

 Number of subjects = 100
```

Comment: The "small loop" is not necessary: `o.accuracy <- sum(diag(matrix))/sum(matrix)`  or `sums <- matrix[cbind(1:nrow(matrix), 1:ncol(matrix))]`